# How to deduct integer from array elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and an integer as input and I would like to sequentially deduct array elements from integer, reducing corresponding array values until they reach zero with '`first-in-first-out`' principle.

I will illustrate my question with an example:

Input:

```
array: [12, 16, 23]
integer: 25
```

Expected output:

```
[0, 3, 23]
 ↑  ↑ See here 25 got subtracted
```

Algorithm:

1. `12-25` (First array element - integer) result: `-13`, so I put first element of array to `0`. And integer to 13.
2. `16-13` (Second array element - integer) resulting `3`, so I put second element of array to `3`. And integer to 0.

(Since `12+16 = 28 > 25` third array element is left intact)

What would be the best strategy to perform this task in PHP?

**EDIT:**

My current code/attempt:

```
public function updateStock(Product $product, $quantity)
{
    $j = true;
    // $quantity is an integer passed as method parameter 
    while ($j) {
        // $stock is an array of objects, each has a quantity property which must be reducted.
        // getActualStocks() method returns stocks with $stock->quantity above zero
        $stock = $product->getActualStocks()[0];
        $initialQuantity = $stock->quantity;
        // this is supposed to update $stock->quantity property 
        $stock = $stock->update($quantity)
        if ($stock->quantity < 0) {
            $quantity = $quantity - $initialQuantity;
            $stock->quantity = 0;
            $stock->save();
        } else {
            $j = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you may want to post code, since folks will see this as a homework question.

Comment: I don't have a working code for this, so far only attempts to solve it using loops with conditions.

Comment: ^^ *only attempts* Show it to us!

Comment: yes , show your attempts, or we wont be able to help you as StackOverflow will close your questions. You should know this.

Comment: updated question with an example. Honestly i don't think it will do any good.

Comment: what if `12-25` equals zero or positive?

Comment: then reduction is applied only to first element, other elements must be left intact

Comment: for your second choice, wouldnt it be `16 - (-13)`?

Comment: No. Following an example: $arr[0] + $arr[1] = 28, $int = 25, $arr[0] + $arr[1] - $int = 3

Comment: I feel like you're not providing enough information.

Comment: what kind of information do you need? I am developing stock management system and I would like to do stock accounting using FIFO stock calculation method. When product is off stock, its quantity must be reducted from corresponding stocks. It is crucial since stocks may differ by supplier and/or purchase price and therefore costs must be calculated correctly.

Comment: The array of numbers will always be the same size (3 elements)? If not, the remaining elements after the third one must be intact as well? Or it must be the last one regardless the array size?

Comment: yes, the number of elements should not change, otherwise I would invent something with `array_shift` :) And the remaining elements must be left intact if $input is less than $arr[0]

Comment: @Rizier123 I've accepted your answer, this is exactly the solution. I did not take into account an option to check array length.

Comment: @paulus You're welcome. What exactly do you mean with: *I did not take into account an option to check array length*  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just loop through your array with a for loop and check each iteration if you aren't at the end of the array AND the `$input` is still bigger than 0.

In each iteration you calculate the `$newInput` by simply subtracting the current array element (`$arr[$i]`) from `$input`. If the result is bigger than 0 assign the result to `$newInput`, otherwise assign 0 and in the next iteration the loop will stop.

Then you make the same thing with the current element in the loop. So that if the result is negative you just assign 0.

At the end of each iteration just assign the `$newInput` to `$input`.

```
<?php

    $arr = [12, 16, 23];
    $input = 25;
    $length = count($arr);

    for($i = 0; $i < $length && $input > 0; $i++) {
        $newInput = $input - $arr[$i] > 0 ? $input - $arr[$i] : 0;
        $arr[$i] = $arr[$i] - $input >= 0 ? $arr[$i] - $input : 0;
        $input = $newInput;
    }

    print_r($arr);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 23
)
```